# How to ceate child Modal window in Python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Python version is 3.7.

Tried to use tkinter.TopLevel(), the second window is created behind the main window.
I need a true child window which is also modal: can't do anything on the main window before the child is closed.

tkinter.messagebox is very similar but I need my own customized window.

Thank you.

Comment: Read up on [Dialog Windows](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This example is pretty much lifted from the *Rolling your own* section at https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html

```
from tkinter import ttk, Tk, Toplevel

root = Tk()
dlg = Toplevel(root)

def dismiss():
    dlg.grab_release()
    dlg.destroy()

ttk.Button(dlg, text="Done", command=dismiss).grid()
dlg.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", dismiss)  # intercept close button
dlg.wait_visibility()  # can't grab until window appears, so we wait
dlg.grab_set()        # ensure all input goes to our window
dlg.lift()  # Bring the dialog to the front.

root.wait_window()     # block until root window is destroyed
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `Toplevel` widget to set a parent modal dialog

```
class topDialog:

def __init__(self, parent):

    top = self.top = Toplevel(parent)

    Label(top, text="Text").pack()
```

Then follow that up with all of your widgets and such.

Comment: Tried it. The top level dialog can go behind the main and it doesn't block interaction with main. It's not modal.